# Fuzzing test in a REST API

Tags: fuzz-testing

I'm trying to do a PoC with [Atheris](https://github.com/google/atheris), and I started to fuzz a endpoint in my api:

`api/v2/pokemon/<fuzz>`

Am I testing something useful with this? Or should I only use fuzz inputs in HTTP body?

Comment: What does the <fuzz> part of the URL do ? Hitting random URLs is one way of fuzzing a system

Comment: In this case, it can retrieve an item from this entity. Goal is to see if the api handles unknown entities as 404, not 500

Comment: If the goal is to just verify 404 on unknown, that doesn't sound like a good candidate for fuzzing.  Just using a random path param once seems sufficient, no need to do it over and over . . .

Comment: Unless those paths include special characters, long strings etc. a fuzzer can do that for you given enough run time